# Android custom view and XML

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, custom-view

I can't figure out what's wrong with the code.. I tried several different things and nothing works.. So I have a class that extends a View because I need to do my own onDraw, and an xml where that custom view is placed. Ok so here's the code..

mainimagehandler.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <net.stojakovic.example.ImageMainHandler.Panel
        android:id="@+id/custom_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

and the activity with the custom view

```
package net.stojakovic.example;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;

public class ImageMainHandler extends SherlockActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainimagehandler);
    }


    public static class Panel extends View {                

        public Panel(Context context) {
            super(context);
            Log.w("Panel","constructor");
        }

        public Panel(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            Log.w("Panel","onDraw");
        }
    }   
}
```

When I do it like this the app crashes with the LogCat message:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.stojakovic.example/net.stojakovic.example.ImageMainHandler}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class net.stojakovic.example.ImageMainHandler.Panel

When I define the custom view in the xml like this, the app doesn't crash but nothing happens, the constructors don't get called

```
<View
    class="net.stojakovic.example.ImageMainHandler.Panel"
    android:id="@+id/custom_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
/>
```

Comment: Have you tried defining the Panel class in a separate file, instead of defining it as an inner static class?

Comment: Yes, it seems that that solved the problem, but every single example I was following had that class within the main activity class.. so frustrating. Thank you!

Comment: It was just a lucky guess :) Glad it helped.